# "Array subscript is not an integer" in C program

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

```
void imprimirTablero(char *tablero[7][7], int *posicionX, int *posicionY)
{
    int i, j;
    tablero[posicionX][posicionY] = 'R';
    for(i = 0; i < LEN(tablero); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < LEN(tablero[0]); j++)
        {
            printf(tablero[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

this method change the char in positionX, positionY and print the new matrix of chars.... please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

You're using a pointer to an integer as an array index for both `posicionX` and `posicionY`.  You need to dereference those pointers:

```
tablero[*posicionX][*posicionY] = 'R';
```

Comment: or more likely, change them to int instead of int pointers

    void imprimirTablero(char *tablero[7][7], int posicionX, int posicionY)

Comment: L. Scott Johnson gave a good advice: if there is no needs to change`posicionX` and `posicionY`, they must be passed as simple int value (by value)

Comment: Right. Your advice was good and correct. And there was no "need" to do it without pointers. But it is more likely that the core mistake was using pointers in the first place, not just in the forgetting to dereference them.

Comment: @VolAnd: and note the assignment of a char to the char pointer on that same line: another indication that the programmer is just confused about the parameter specification format.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a 2D array of pointers, not chars, and two pointers to ints, not ints. I think you want:

```
void imprimirTablero(char tablero[7][7], int posicionX, int posicionY)
```

judging by

```
tablero[posicionX][posicionY] = 'R';
```